# python library for file upload and persistent connections?

Tags: python, httpwebrequest, twisted, pycurl

I tried urllib{2}, pycurl and I'm looking at twisted's new http client.
But:

- I found urllib2 difficult to perform a file upload
- pycurl multi looks right but unpythonic
- twisted's http client does not support persistent connection (didn't check the file upload capability)

Is there any other alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PiCloud](http://www.picloud.com)'s library uses urllib2_file which easily does upload via multipart data.  I forget where we got the module (we later modified it).  the urllib2_file is covered under a BSD license.

Answer (score 1):

I rolled my own on top of `httplib` before discovering [urllib3](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/urllib3/1.0.1), which does both of these things.